Unmet dependencies and broken packages after installing libstdc++6
When trying to use screenshare with audio on vesktop, I got an error from the app that read "your c++ library is too old to run venmic", which prompted me to try and update it.
I followed the steps:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libstdc++6

I also updated my gcc through the software manager right after.
The packages that were removed from these commands were:
intel-media-va-driver:i386 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libicu70:i386 libigdgmm12:i386 libllvm15:i386
  libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libva-glx2:i386 libxml2:i386
  mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 steam:i386
  steam-libs-i386:i386 va-driver-all:i386

I didn't think much of it since it was getting replaced by other libraries, sadly I don't remember which ones, though I didn't notice the "nvidia-firmware" or "steam-devices" packages. I also thought that it would be simple to undo this procedure afterwards so I kept it going. Vesktop was working afterwards but some other apps were not, so I then tried undoing it by reinstalling all the removed apps, assuming it would remove the libstdc++6 and replace it with a different one. Here's what happened:
sudo apt install intel-media-va-driver:i386 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libicu70:i386 libigdgmm12:i386 libllvm15:i386
  libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libva-glx2:i386 libxml2:i386
  mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 steam:i386
  steam-libs-i386:i386 va-driver-all:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 intel-media-va-driver:i386 : Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: libgl1-amber-dri:i386 but it is not installable
 libicu70:i386 : Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libigdgmm12:i386 : Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libllvm15:i386 : Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 12) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
libglx-mesa0:i386: command not found
libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386: command not found
mesa-va-drivers:i386: command not found
steam-libs-i386:i386: command not found

I tried removing the libstdc++6 package to see if it would be replaced by something else and I got this:
sudo apt-get remove libstdc++6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.12) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
 mintsources : Depends: python3-apt but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-gi-cairo but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-pycurl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-requests but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mint-common (>= 2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-vte-2.91 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-xapp-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: lsb-release but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

I tried installing libstdc++6:i386 and this happened:
sudo apt install libstdc++6:i386           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.12) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but it is not installable
 mintsources : Depends: python3-apt but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-gi-cairo but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-pycurl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-requests but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mint-common (>= 2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-vte-2.91 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-xapp-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: lsb-release but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

I tried fixing the broken packages and got this:
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  i965-va-driver:i386 libatomic1:i386 libbrotli1:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libedit2:i386
  libelf1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
  libgnutls30:i386 libhogweed6:i386 libnettle8:i386 libnm0:i386
  libp11-kit0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libsensors5:i386
  libtasn1-6:i386 libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386 libvulkan1:i386
  libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386
  nvidia-firmware-535-535.171.04 steam-devices
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.

I then noticed that Steam was gone from my apps, and when trying to install it again, I ran into an error as well:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  apt: Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.12) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but it is not installable
  mintsources: Depends: python3-apt but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-gi-cairo but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-pycurl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-requests but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mint-common (>= 2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-vte-2.91 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-xapp-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: lsb-release but it is not going to be installed

So what happened and what do I do? I've never had this problem before, and I've used outside repos before. I haven't run the autoremove command out of fear of breaking things further, but it seems like those packages are the ones causing problems. I'm running Linux Mint 21.1 and I'm not sure which c++ library is the proper one for this system, I'd just like to get things back to how they were.
The apt policy command for libstdc++6 and libstdc++6:i386:
apt policy libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386
libstdc++6:
  Installed: 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~22.04
  Candidate: 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~22.04
  Version table:
 *** 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~22.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     12-20220319-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libstdc++6:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04
  Version table:
     12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     12-20220319-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages


Could you [edit] your question to show the output of apt policy libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386?

I updated it and it looks like both are installed???

The i386 package isn’t installed.

To undo the installation you need to revert to the distribution libstdc++6 package:
sudo apt install libstdc++6=12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04

You should remove the PPA you added. You might also need to downgrade GCC packages.
Once all that’s done, you’ll be able to re-install the i386 packages.
